# implementing maxmind's free GeoLiteCity DB on a C# webform?

Tags: c#, maxmind

Has anyone successfully utilized MaxMind's data and C# code on a webform? I would appreciate any insight. If you can provide a walk through of the implementation process and perhaps some sample C# code that works for you, I would truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing max-mind is very simple, in C# we have Nuget package for max-mind Db reader

- Install-Package MaxMind.GeoIP2 -Version 2.6.0
- After that you can use max-mind db reader to read your db.
- Finally take the read data as an object and obtain the details you want.

Example:

```
string path = @"c:\MaxMindDb\GeoIP2-City.mmdb";
using (var reader = new Reader(path, MaxMind.Db.FileAccessMode.Memory))
{
     var data = reader.Find(ip).ToString();
     var GeoData= JToken.Parse(data);
     string CountryCode = GeoData["continent"]["code"].ToString() ?? null;
     ...
```